# Kendo drop down list does not default to originial chart appearance

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

Here is a preview of a dropdown list we have for our chart widgets with Kendo. When you click on a chart ex: donut, the dropdown does not default to the same appearance as the original chart. This chart pictured is a donut, but the dropdown defaults to Area chart. I have added a BindTo, but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
<td class="inputlabel">Appearance:</td>
                        <td class="inputfield">
                            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                            .Name(uniqueWidgetID + "-SummaryChartType")
                            .BindTo(Model.WidgetSubType);
                            .Items(items =>
                        {
                               items.Add().Text("Area").Value("area");
                               items.Add().Text("Bar").Value("bar");
                               items.Add().Text("Donut").Value("donut");
                               items.Add().Text("Column").Value("column");
                               items.Add().Text("Line").Value("line");
                               items.Add().Text("Pie").Value("pie");
                           })
                           .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "width80" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that using BindTo and Items at the same time would work.
BindTo and Items are doing the same thing they are populating dropdown. You must choose which method is preferred for you. You can use BindTo if you want to bind Model property which is IEnumerable. Items requires Action parameter which is fine if you want to hard code Items in dropdown.

Remove BindTo from widget, add Id in HtmlAttributes

for example you have a javascript function that is fired when user clicks some chart

```
function ChartClicked(chartType)
{
    var dropdownlist = $("#"+ 'dropdownlist name').data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdownlist.value(chartType);
}
```